# How to render a mediawiki page with api?

Tags: mediawiki-api

I should want insert a wikipedia page in another web page, inside a div, with some sort of mediawiki api call in javascript, without all "edit" buttons, menu and so on ; only the article.

I understand nothing about how to render a wikimedia page in element of a web page.

I don't understand how to use http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats because I should want html format.

I have seen http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse but I read on the exemple it's for debugging stuff ?? And in http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#View_and_render I've seen render action, but it's deprecated ?

So, how it's possible to do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything on the page you linked to about `action=parse` being only for debugging. I think that's exactly what you should do.

The API won't give you the HTML directly, it will be enclosed in JSON (or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)), but you can get the HTML out of that.

Comment: If I clic on http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse and the exemple http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=[[foo]]%20[[API:Query|bar]]%20[http://www.example.com/%20baz] I see _You are looking at the HTML representation of the XML format.
HTML is good for debugging, but is unsuitable for application use._. Anyway, than you for your help.

Comment: @Istao But that's referring to only to the format, not to the `parse` method. What you should do is to add `format=json` to your query, that's not for debugging.